# Query is working on Impala but not on hive

Tags: sql, hive, impala

The below query works perfectly on Impala.

```sql
create table test1 stored as parquet as 
select bac_key, tu_analytic_key, 
  row_number() over (partition by bac_key order by min(rn)) as new_rownum 
from test2  
group by bac_key, tu_analytic_key order by bac_key, min(rn);
```

When I run this on Hive I get the below error.

> Error: Error while compiling statement:
> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]:
> Line 1:301 Invalid column reference 'rn'

rn is a column in the test2 table.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If I remove the min(rn) from the order by clause, it executes fine on hive. But I need the min(rn) in the order by.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a case of Hive not supporting aggregate functions in order by, you can wrap the query and then use order by on the requisite column as below.

```
create table test1 stored as parquet 
as 
    Select 
        bac_key
      , tu_analytic_key
      , new_rownum
      ,min_rn
      from
       (select 
            bac_key
          , tu_analytic_key
          , row_number() over (partition by bac_key order by min(rn)) as new_rownum
          , min(rn) As min_rn
        from test2 
           group by bac_key
         , tu_analytic_key) T
order by bac_key, min_rn;

Alter table test1 replace columns(bac_key string, tu_analytic_key string, new_rownum int);
```

Comment: Hi. I still get the same error.

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:466 Invalid table alias or column reference 'min_rn': (possible column names are: bac_key, tu_analytic_key, new_rownum) (state=42000,code=10004)

Comment: The order by clause is not able to read the min_rn field from the subquery. Please help. thanks.

Comment: What if you add the min_rn column in the outer select? Does it work then? I know that you don’t need min_rn in your table but just to check if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes it works if I add the min_rn in the outer select.But as you said, i dont need the min_rn in the table.

Comment: Edited my answer above. You can do something like that. Keep min_rn just so that the order by work. Then exclude the min_rn column from the table using an alter statement. Or you can just create test2 with all the column and then just do create table test1 as select col1, col2, col3 from test2; and then drop test2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222603/discussion-between-somy-and-sawan-s).